# Data retrieval from 5.25 floppy disks

Tags: data-preservation

Can anyone direct one toward a service which can retrieve data stored on 5.25 single-sided dual-density floppy disks (MS-DOS 1.25, written using EasyWriter, on a Sanyo MBC-550)?

Comment: A question asking for pointers to services is not exactly on topic here. You may want to use your favoured search engine.

Comment: At present, this is a [shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). As such, I'm closing it. Please read the [tour], [ask], and then the previously linked blog post if you think you can improve it.

Answer (score 4):

A web search finds a number of companies which provide this sort of service, but I have never used any (and this isn’t the place to endorse one either).

There are some volunteers around the globe who might be able to help — the Archive Team has [a list of volunteers](https://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Rescuing_Floppy_Disks#Methods_of_Transfer_(Volunteers)), and a trip to vintage computing forums will find more. Terry Stewart (in New Zealand) also offers a similar service, albeit [not for free](https://www.classic-computers.org.nz/floppy-disk-file-extraction-service.htm).

Comment: Agreed. Get quotes from specialists. The floppy disks may need preparation before any attempt is made to read them.

Comment: The archive team link is a good one.